# Stepper Motor over heating and optimal decay settings

Tags: motor, driver, stepper-motor, debugging

Motor is overheating at 50% decay settings (Driver : TB6560HQ), so what is optimum decay settings , need to increase or decrease?

I have basic understanding that if 100% decay, possibility is high for shoot through of MOSFET? Am I correct in my consideration?

Driver : [TB6560HQ](http://www.rapp-instruments.de/Elektronik/Messtechnik/stepperdriver/images/TB6560HQ.pdf)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet says nothing about shoot-through, so we must presume the chip has been designed to avoid it.

I bet your motor is overheating because you are pushing too much current through it. A higher decay setting should reduce average current draw, so you may find the motor runs a bit cooler at 100%. However the purpose of decay is to decelerate the motor faster, not to compensate for too much current.

You can reduce current by increasing the value of the sense resistors on NFA and NFB, or by changing the torque setting inputs on TQ1 and TQ2.